# Want a dedicated button AjaxFileManager for TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I want to add a button in tinyMCE Editor which will open up the AjaxFileBrowser and selecting a file and clicking **select** Button will return the file path in the editor, as it does in the image/media url field of insert image/media windows.

Actually, I need a way out to add a direct way to access the AjaxFileManager.

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.addButton('MyButton', {
        title : 'MyButton',
        image : './images/copy.jpg',
        onclick : function() {
        ajaxfilemanager('','','file',window); // The first arguement is return field as I know but how to use it??
            ed.focus();
            ed.selection.setContent('<tittle>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</tittle>');
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any great documentation for this. Please Suggest Me!!